# Orchard Placement.info Match Tenant Relative Url

Tags: orchardcms

Is it possible to match a tenant relative url in placement.info? I have a theme that needs to target a tenant's home page. This works fine if the tenant isn't using a url prefix but breaks on ones that do.

```
<Match ContentType="Page">
  <Match DisplayType="Detail">
    <Match Path="~/">
      ...
    </Match>
  </Match>
</Match>
```

Comment: What does the "tenant relative url" looks like?

Comment: It would be a way to specify that a url is relative to whatever the current tenant root is that is running a particular module. In some cases this may be the same as ~/ but in other cases it could by ~/some-tenant. I would envision something similar to tokens like {Tenant.Root}some/relative/path.

Comment: I think you need to extend the code responsible for the placement handling as the official documentation does not state that tokens are possible. Perhaps you can submit a patch?